# Delete Method's return value in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

According to Microsoft Developer Network, both `Range.Delete` and `Worksheet.Delete` method will return a value. However, by using the `MsgBox` function I can only view the return value for the `Worksheet.Delete` method but have no luck with the `Range.Delete` method.
The code I used is `MsgBox Worksheets("Sheet1").Delete`

Here are the two articles from MSDN for your information:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837404.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834641.aspx

Comment: If you need help with code, you need to post the code that is not working.  Do this by editing your question. Please read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Your `Worksheets` example returns `True` for me, as does `MsgBox ActiveSheet.Range("a2").Delete`.

Comment: I used MsgBox Range("A1").Delete and an error is return. I tried MsgBox ActiveSheet.Range("a2").Delete and it works. But then I have another question. Why is ActiveSheet necessary in this scenario? Range("A2") = 16 is fine without following ActiveSheet.

Comment: Can you paste your code and the values of the ranges in question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of the use `Range` method that does return the value:

```
MsgBox ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Delete
```

HTH

Comment: I used MsgBox Range("A1").Delete and an error is return. I tried MsgBox ActiveSheet.Range("a2").Delete and it works. But then I have another question. Why is ActiveSheet necessary in this scenario? Range("A2") = 16 is fine without following ActiveSheet.

Comment: Good question. For me `MsgBox Range("A1").Delete` gives "True" in the message box. What is the error and what do you have in the cell? If I have a Chart active, not a sheet, then I get an error. Do you have your sheet protected?

Comment: hi ib11, I was using Excel on iMac and I got an error with the code MsgBox Range("A1").Delete
However, when I use the same code on Windows Excel 2013, I can get a "True". The problem is solved.

Comment: Compile error:
Expected Function or variable
(ThisWorkbook 6:18)

Comment: Hm. I don't know the iMac, but try adding a `()` after `Delete`, like so: `MsgBox Range("A1").Delete()`